# Uncaught ReferenceError: autocomp is not defined

Tags: javascript, undefined

I have this error displaying in Firefox Developer Console.
Tried and failing to solve it and would appreciate any help.

Thanks

```
addDOMLoadEvent(Start_Tags);

function Start_Tags() {
    autocomp.start('tags','torrents');  
    resize('tags'); 
}

function clicked(tag) {
    
    if (tag===null || tag=='') return;
    if($('#tags').raw().value == "") {
        $('#tags').raw().value = tag; 
    } else {
        $('#tags').raw().value = $('#tags').raw().value + ' ' + tag;
    }
    resize('tags'); 
    $('#torrentssearch').raw().value ='';
    $('#torrentssearch').raw().focus();
    //CursorToEnd($('#tags').raw());
    
}
```

Comment: Like the error said, `autocomp` is not defined.

Comment: Please can you tell me how to define it in that code?

Comment: Where do you get this code? `autocomp` looks like some sort of a library but you forgot to include it.

Comment: That is all the code in one file named tag_autocomplete.js

Comment: Please provide URL of the  tag_autocomplete.js to it's content.